# SQL Server 2014 Word Count

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a SQL Server database that I'm searching for keywords.

All I need to know is how many of the keywords appear in a column.

For example

```
red,green,blue
```

If the column looked like this

```
I like red shoes but not blue
```

It would return the number 2

If the column looked like this

```
I like red shoes and green shoes, but green are my favourite
```

It would also return the number 2

2 of the keywords were found even though one was found twice.

Im open to using full text index or anything that is required, but Im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string splitter for this. Here is the [**DelimitedSplit8K**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) function by Jeff Moden.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(8000) = 'I like red shoes and green shoes, but green are my favourite'

SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM)
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@str, ' ')
WHERE
    Item IN('red', 'green', 'blue')
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8018f/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT b.LineText, count(*) from 
FROM
(
select 'RED' Colors
union
select 'GREEN'
union
select 'BLUE'
) a
JOIN
(
SELECT 'I like red shoes but not blue' LineText
UNION
SELECT 'I like red shoes and green shoes, but green are my favourite'
) b ON b.LineText LIKE '%'+a.Colors+'%'
group by b.LineText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
WITH C(txt) AS(
  SELECT 'I like red shoes but not blue'
  UNION
  SELECT 'I like red shoes and green shoes, but green are my favourite'
)
SELECT COUNT(txt)
FROM C WHERE txt LIKE '%green%'
OR txt LIKE '%blue%'
OR txt LIKE '%red%'
```

Comment: WITH C(txt) AS(
  SELECT 'I like red shoes but not blue or green'
  UNION
  SELECT 'I like red shoes and green shoes, but green are my favourite'
)
SELECT COUNT(txt)
FROM C WHERE txt LIKE '%green%'
OR txt LIKE '%blue%'
OR txt LIKE '%red%'

Comment: Doesnt work because if I change that first one to have green also, it still returns two as the count, I need the count of words rather than the count of rows with the words.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
     create table #temp(color varchar(500))
insert into #temp(color) values('red')
insert into #temp(color) values('green')
insert into #temp(color) values('blue')

Create table #temp2(string varchar(max))
insert into #temp2(string) values('I like red shoes and green shoes, but green are my favourite')
insert into #temp2(string) values('I like red shoes and green shoes')

select string,count(*) from #temp inner join #temp2 on PATINDEX('%'+color+'%',string)>0
group by string
```